# cutting a variable into pieces in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, statistics, categorical-data

I'm trying to `cut()` my data `D` into 3 pieces: `[0-4]`, `[5-12]`, `[13-40]` (*see pic below*). But I wonder how to exactly define my `breaks` in `cut` to achieve that?

Here is my data and R code:

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/t.csv", h = T)


 table(cut(D$time, breaks = c(0, 5, 9, 12))) ## what should breaks be?

 # (0,5]  (5,9] (9,12]  # cuts not how I want the 3 pieces .
 #  228     37     10
```

[image]

Comment: In the code example you write, that with a `9` in breaks it does not cut the way you want it, which has not a `9` in it. Apart from that superfluous `9` can you specify, what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation (a,b] means ">a and <=b".

So, to get your desired result, just define the cuts so you get the grouping that you want, including a lower and upper bound:

```
table(cut(D$time, breaks=c(-1, 4, 12, 40)))

## (-1,4]  (4,12] (12,40] 
##   319      47      20
```

You may also find it helpful to look at the two arguments `right=FALSE`, which changes the endpoints of the intervals from `(a,b]` to `[a,b)`, and `include.lowest`, which includes the lowest `breaks` value (in the OP's example, this is `[0,5]` with closed brackets on the lower bound). You can also use infinity. Here's an example with a couple of those options put to use:

```
table(cut(D$time, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 12, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE))

## [-Inf,4]    (4,12] (12, Inf] 
##     319        47        20
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the right buckets,  but the interval notation would need tweaking. Assuming all times are integers.  Might need to tweak the labels manually - each time  you have an right-open interval notation,  replace the factor label with a closed interval notation. Use your best string 'magic'

Personally, I like to make sure all possibilities are covered.  Perhaps future data from this process might exceed 40?  I like to put an upper bound of `+Inf` in all my cuts.  This prevents `NA` from creeping into the data.

What `cut` needs is a 'whole numbers only` option.

```r
F=cut(D$time,c(0,5,13,40),include.lowest = TRUE,right=FALSE)
# the below levels hard coded but you could write a loop to turn all labels
# of the form [m,n) into [m,n-1]
levels(F)[1:2]=c('[0,4]','[5,12]')
```

Typically there would be more analysis before final results are obtained, so I wouldn't sweat the labels too much until the work is closer to complete.

Here are my results

```
 > table(F) 
 F
 [0,4]  [5,12]  [13,40] 
 319      47      20
```

Answer (score 1):

R can compare integers to floats, like in

```
> 6L >= 8.5
[1] FALSE
```

Thus you can use floats as `breaks` in cut such as in

```
table(cut(D$time, breaks = c(-.5, 4.5, 12.5, 40.5)))
```

For integers this fullfills your bucket definition of `[0-4], [5-12], [13-40]` without you having to think to much about square brackets against round brackets.

A fancy alternative would be clustering around the mean of you buckets as in

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/t.csv", h = T)
D$cluster <- kmeans(D$time, center = c(4/2, (5+12)/2, (13+40)/2))$cluster
plot(D$time, rnorm(nrow(D)), col=D$cluster)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add two aditional arguments `right` and `include.lowest` to your code!

```
table(cut(D$time, breaks = c(0, 5, 13, 40), right=FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE))
```

In the case of `right=FALSE` the intervals should be closed on the left and open on the right such that you would have your desired result. `include.lowest=TRUE` causes that your highest break value (here 40) is included to the last interval.
Result:

```
[0,5)  [5,13) [13,40] 
 319      47      20
```

Vice versa you can write:

```
table(cut(D$time, breaks = c(0, 4, 12, 40), right=TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE))
```

with the result:

```
 [0,4]  (4,12] (12,40] 
  319      47      20
```

Both mean exact what you looking for:

```
[0,4]  [5,12] [13,40] 
 319      47      20
```